# Merging data with left_join, but taking only one value from a set of rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to merge two data frames. Specifically, I need to get a total number of cases that happen on a given shift and then add that total number to a different data frame.

I first create a new column called "num.cases" from df1 below.

```
df1 <- structure(list(Person = c(
  "A", "A",
  "B", "B", "B", "B",
  "B", "B", "B", "B",
  "B", "B", "B", "B",
  "C", "C", "C", "C",
  "C", "C"
), Day = structure(c(
  17539,
  17539, 17539, 17539, 17539, 17540, 17540, 17540, 17540, 17540,
  17541, 17541, 17541, 17541, 17542, 17542, 17542, 17546, 17546,
  17546
), class = "Date"), Shift = structure(c(
  32L, 32L, 32L, 32L,
  32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 34L,
  33L, 33L, 33L
), .Label = c(
  "1st Call M-F", "1st Call Wknd AM",
  "1st Call Wknd PM", "2nd Call M-F", "2nd Call Wknd AM", "2nd Call Wknd PM",
  "3rd Call M-F", "3rd Call Wknd AM", "3rd Call Wknd PM", "4th Call M-F",
  "4th Call Wknd AM", "AIC 0700-1700 @ 1.5 PTS", "MCA AIC1", "MCA OB/T PM",
  "CCRM", "CROB Day Sup", "CROB Night", "CROB Wknd Day", "CROB Wknd Night",
  "CVCALL", "Peds CV", "FLEX", "LAH OB Day", "LAH OB Night", "LAH TR Day M-F (Suping)",
  "LAH TR Night M-F", "LAH TR Wknd Day (Sup)1900", "LAH TR Wknd Night 1900",
  "MCA AIC 24", "MCA AIC2", "ORD1", "ORD2", "ORD3", "ORD4", "Peds 1",
  "Peds 2", "PSL OB Day", "Post Call Working 3pts/hr", "PSL OB Night",
  "Rose OB Day", "Rose OB Night", "SR OB Day", "SMC OB AM M-F",
  "SMC OB PM M-F", "SMC OB Wknd Day", "SMC OB Wknd Night", "SMC TR Day M-F (Suping)",
  "SMC TR Night M-F S", "SMC TR Wknd Day (Suping)", "SMC TR Wknd Night S",
  "SR OB Night", "SRT Day Sup M-F", "SRT Night M-F", "SRT Wknd Night",
  "SUPERVISING 1500", "SUPERVISING 1700", "SUPERVISING 1900", "SUPERVISING 2100",
  "SRT Wknd Day (Sup) 1900", "Liver Call", "PC CV"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(
  NA,
  -20L
), class = "data.frame")
```

I then want to add "num.cases" to df4.

```
df4 <- structure(list(
  Person = c(
    "A", "A",
    "B", "B", "B", "B",
    "B", "B", "B", "B",
    "B", "B", "B", "B",
    "C", "C", "C", "C",
    "C", "C"
  ), Day = structure(c(
    17539,
    17540, 17541, 17542, 17543, 17546, 17547, 17548, 17550, 17553,
    17554, 17555, 17556, 17558, 17559, 17560, 17561, 17562, 17563,
    17564
  ), class = "Date"), Shift = structure(c(
    32L, 32L, 33L, 34L,
    31L, 33L, 32L, 1L, 32L, 32L, 10L, 31L, 32L, 11L, 11L, 31L, 32L,
    32L, 32L, 33L
  ), .Label = c(
    "1st Call M-F", "1st Call Wknd AM",
    "1st Call Wknd PM", "2nd Call M-F", "2nd Call Wknd AM", "2nd Call Wknd PM",
    "3rd Call M-F", "3rd Call Wknd AM", "3rd Call Wknd PM", "4th Call M-F",
    "4th Call Wknd AM", "AIC 0700-1700 @ 1.5 PTS", "MCA AIC1", "MCA OB/T PM",
    "CCRM", "CROB Day Sup", "CROB Night", "CROB Wknd Day", "CROB Wknd Night",
    "CVCALL", "Peds CV", "FLEX", "LAH OB Day", "LAH OB Night", "LAH TR Day M-F (Suping)",
    "LAH TR Night M-F", "LAH TR Wknd Day (Sup)1900", "LAH TR Wknd Night 1900",
    "MCA AIC 24", "MCA AIC2", "ORD1", "ORD2", "ORD3", "ORD4", "Peds 1",
    "Peds 2", "PSL OB Day", "Post Call Working 3pts/hr", "PSL OB Night",
    "Rose OB Day", "Rose OB Night", "SR OB Day", "SMC OB AM M-F",
    "SMC OB PM M-F", "SMC OB Wknd Day", "SMC OB Wknd Night", "SMC TR Day M-F (Suping)",
    "SMC TR Night M-F S", "SMC TR Wknd Day (Suping)", "SMC TR Wknd Night S",
    "SR OB Night", "SRT Day Sup M-F", "SRT Night M-F", "SRT Wknd Night",
    "SUPERVISING 1500", "SUPERVISING 1700", "SUPERVISING 1900", "SUPERVISING 2100",
    "SRT Wknd Day (Sup) 1900", "Liver Call", "PC CV"
  ), class = "factor"),
  Total_points = c(
    15, 15, 18, 21, 7.5, 18, 15, 54, 15, 15,
    24, 12, 15, 12, 12, 12, 15, 15, 15, 18
  )
), row.names = c(
  NA,
  20L
), class = "data.frame")
```

If you reproduce my code below, you will get many NAs after merging because I took the first 20 rows of each data frame.

My code is below and it works for my purposes, but I'm curious if there is a faster way to do this.

```
library(dplyr)
## Create new DF that includes column with number of cases during given Day & Shift
df2 = df1 %>% 
  group_by(Person, Day, Shift) %>% 
  mutate(num.cases = n()) %>% 
  select(Person, Day, Shift, num.cases)

## Include only one row from a single day in order to join this data with df4
### this takes forever to run
df3 = df2 %>% 
  distinct(-Shift, .keep_all = TRUE) 

## Add num.cases to df4
df5 = df4 %>%
  left_join(df3 %>%
              group_by(Person, Day, Shift),
            by = c("Person", "Day", "Shift")) %>%
  select(Person, Day, Shift, Total_points, num.cases) %>%
  glimpse()
```

Comment: Instead of only showing the codes. Please also show what is the data you have and what's your desired output. You can sample your data.

Comment: Please post some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little late, but I believe you could use `summarize` instead of `mutate`. Then you don't need to use `distinct`.

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Person, Day, Shift) %>% 
  summarize(num.cases = n())
```

Yields

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   Person, Day [6]
  Person Day        Shift num.cases
  <chr>  <date>     <fct>     <int>
1 A      2018-01-08 ORD2          2
2 B      2018-01-08 ORD2          3
3 B      2018-01-09 ORD2          5
4 B      2018-01-10 ORD3          4
5 C      2018-01-11 ORD4          3
6 C      2018-01-15 ORD3          3
```

You can combine the steps into one with

```
df4 %>%
  left_join(df1 %>% 
              group_by(Person, Day, Shift) %>% 
              summarise(num.cases = n()),
            by = c("Person", "Day", "Shift"))
```

Results with

```
   Person        Day            Shift Total_points num.cases
1       A 2018-01-08             ORD2         15.0         2
2       A 2018-01-09             ORD2         15.0        NA
3       B 2018-01-10             ORD3         18.0         4
4       B 2018-01-11             ORD4         21.0        NA
5       B 2018-01-12             ORD1          7.5        NA
6       B 2018-01-15             ORD3         18.0        NA
7       B 2018-01-16             ORD2         15.0        NA
8       B 2018-01-17     1st Call M-F         54.0        NA
9       B 2018-01-19             ORD2         15.0        NA
10      B 2018-01-22             ORD2         15.0        NA
11      B 2018-01-23     4th Call M-F         24.0        NA
12      B 2018-01-24             ORD1         12.0        NA
13      B 2018-01-25             ORD2         15.0        NA
14      B 2018-01-27 4th Call Wknd AM         12.0        NA
15      C 2018-01-28 4th Call Wknd AM         12.0        NA
16      C 2018-01-29             ORD1         12.0        NA
17      C 2018-01-30             ORD2         15.0        NA
18      C 2018-01-31             ORD2         15.0        NA
19      C 2018-02-01             ORD2         15.0        NA
20      C 2018-02-02             ORD3         18.0        NA
```